# What AWS Elastic Transcoder HLS format meets Apple's 192 kpbs streaming requirement?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I'm reading that Apple requires streaming HTTP Live Streaming to meet this requirement

```
When authoring your content for HTTP Live Streaming over cellular, you must provide a baseline stream with a maximum measured bitrate of 192 kbps in addition to any other higher bitrate streams.
```

I'm using AWS Elastic Transcoder to convert a video file using the preset HLS 1k, which says this is the bit rate

```
Bit Rate
872
```

I've used Apple's mediafilevalidator and this is the output

```
Discontinuity: sequence: 0, parsed segment count: 3 of 3, duration: 9.067 sec, average: 1013.71 kb/s, max: 1176.55 kb/s
Track ID: 1
Audio Codec: AAC-LC
Audio sample rate: 44100 Hz
Audio channel layout: Stereo (L R)
Track ID: 2
Video Codec: avc1
Video profile: Main
Video level: 3.1
Video resolution: 243x432
Video average IDR interval: 3.000000, Standard deviation: 0.000000
Video frame rate: 30.000
```

Does the HLS 1M stream meet Apple's 192kpbs requirement? I can't really tell based off the info.

If HLS 1k meets 1MB/s, then HLS 400k meets 400kpbs, then there's no lower option and I need to include a purely audio stream?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi!
Did you get an answer to this?